# How to migrate from header-only project?

Tags: c++, header-only

We have a header-only C++ code base (VS 2010, Eclipse, Makefile) with about 450 files (3.6 MB). Everyday work started to become harder because of long (4 minutes) compilation times. A smaller part of it, about 20%, is templated, but others are simple classes with some template methods here and there. We are thinking about migrating the 80% to have separate `.cpp` and `.h` files.

First, I would change every templated file from `.h` to `.hpp`. That would define the scope. After that I just see tons of manual work. Maybe with some help of Visual Assist's *Move implementation to source* feature. At the end I am thinking in partial unity builds (compilation units of 5..20 `.cpp` files), but that can be done after everything.

Can you think of any better ways than manual work on about 360 files? Any speedups?

Comment: You could write your own tool to parse the C++ headers and break them out into .CPP/.H. Depending on how long it takes to write the tool, it might save you time over doing everything manually.

Comment: Ask the boost guys. They started out as header only.

Comment: @Bathsheba: But they never converted any header only parts.

Comment: @Paladine: in that case, libclang would be your best friend.